# How to create a blank png image in vb.net

Tags: .net, wpf, image

This seems so trivial, yet I cannot find where or how to do this.

i need to be able to create on the fly blank png in a WPF project. Size of the png does not matter, I just need to be able to create one and save it on a specifiy path by pressing a button.

For some reason, I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ Maybe this will help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `Bitmap` object and manipulate it as you need. The `Bitmap` object has a `Save` method that let's you specify what file format to save it as, one choice being Png.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
bm.Save(filename, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```